# Different SimpleDateFormat parsen

Tags: java, date, validation, simpledateformat

I want to check if a date matches one of my defined patterns. Please see below my code.

```
date = null

List<String> formatStrings = Arrays.asList("yyyy-MM-dd", "dd.MM.yyyy", "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy/MM/dd", "dd/MM/yyyy");

        for (String formatStr: formatStrings) {
            try {
                dateType = new Date(new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr).parse(myCol).getTime());

            } catch (ParseException e) {}
        }
        return date;
```

I also tried:

```
 try { 
   for.. }
 catch {}
```

I have also written an unit test to test if my function is working but it is only working when my variable has a pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd" (so the first one in the list). And if I have any other pattern it shows an Exception...

Can you please help me? Which line did I write wrong?

Comment: What exception did you get? Maybe catch and ignore that one?

Comment: No, it just checks if my var has the first pattern but not the others... and if it has not the first it goes directly to the Exception

Comment: Date is a date. It cannot match or not match patterns. String representation of a date may match pattern. This is sort of taks for regular expression application I think.

Comment: I suspect you want `return dateType;` *inside* the try block - otherwise you're trying all the patterns even if the first one succeeds.

Comment: @AlexeyR.: To my mind a regex would be really painful. While Date is an instant in time (not a date), SimpleDateFormat definitely *does* match or not match patterns.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat#parse()` already produces a Date, there is no need to create another instance using `new Date()` out of the first one.

Comment: @AlexeyR. - yes, but it still checks only if the var has the first pattern in the list

Comment: FYI, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See `DateTimeFormatter` and `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

Comment: Could you please indent your code properly? When the code is readily readable, a lot of people here will be much more inclined to giving you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the industry-leading modern *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

## *java.time*

Switch to using `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

A couple of your expected formats are predefined by `DateTimeFormatter`, each being variations on the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For the other three formats, we define a formatting pattern.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Demo
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Demo app = new Demo ();
        app.demo ();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        // ("yyyy-MM-dd", "dd.MM.yyyy", "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy/MM/dd", "dd/MM/yyyy"
        final List < DateTimeFormatter > formatterList = List.of (
                DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE ,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd.MM.uuuu" ) ,
                DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuu/M/dd" ) ,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
        );

        final List < String > inputs = List.of ( "2020-01-23" , "23.01.2020" , "20200123" , "2020/01/23" , "23/01/2020" );

        for ( String input : inputs )
        {
            LocalDate localDate = null;
            for ( DateTimeFormatter formatter : formatterList )
            {
                try
                {
                    localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , formatter );
                    if ( ! localDate.equals ( LocalDate.of ( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ) )
                    {
                        throw new IllegalStateException ( "Oops! Unexpected result. " + input + " ➙ " + localDate );
                    }
                    System.out.println ( input + " ➙ " + localDate );
                    break; // Bail out of this inner FOR loop, as we have successfully parsed this input.
                } catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
                {
                    // Swallow exception, as we expect most to fail.
                }
            }
            Objects.requireNonNull ( localDate , "Oops, unexpected input: " + input );
        }
    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/eiePgB).

> 2020-01-23 ➙ 2020-01-23
>
> 23.01.2020 ➙ 2020-01-23
>
> 20200123 ➙ 2020-01-23
>
> 2020/01/23 ➙ 2020-01-23
>
> 23/01/2020 ➙ 2020-01-23